# How to wrap many <span> within <div>

Tags: css, word-wrap

I have a `<div>` with hard-coded width. Inside the `<div>` are several hundred `<span>` tags. Can I wrap the spans so that line spacing is correct and wrapping is between spans? I use `word-wrap: break-word` and it looks a mess.

Here is pseudo code.

```
span {
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px dotted #cccccc;
  padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px; 
    }
div {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  width: 800px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

<div>
  <span>stuff</span>
  <span>more stuff</span>
  <span>even more stuff</span>
  .
  .
  .
</div>
```

Thanks!

EDIT for clarification: There should be multiple spans on each line, and wrapping should be between spans.

Comment: I'm lost at what you are trying to achieve. Would setting display:block and width:100% solve the issue?

Comment: my answer is based on you cannot edit the html or edit it with any kind of javascript

Comment: i am more confused with that edit, multi spans on a line but with wrapping between spans - does that not contradict each other? or do you mean it will wrap only when the max character has been reached on that line then on the next /span it should wrap

Comment: It's the same behaviour as floating blocks: fit as many blocks as possible on a line and then continue on the next one without ever cutting a block in half. Inline-block avoids problems caused by floats (.clearfix and so on) but creates another one due to whitespace between two span displayed as a space and that needs a fix (though not here, span are not glued together)

Comment: Add `display: inline-block;` attribute to each `<span>` - Please refer http://getbootstrap.com/components/#callout-labels-inline-block

Answer (score 27, accepted):

EDIT (2017): Flexbox with wrap `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap` is compatible with IE10+ (and Android 4.4+) and will allow versatile alignments both horizontally (justified, aligned to the left or right, `space-around`, centered) and vertically (`align-items`) with also versatile spacing between lines (`align-content`… if an height is set, in general).
Bonus: no ~4px whitespace between items to take care of as with `inline-block`. You do pretty much what you want: no gutter, `flex: 1 1 auto` or `padding: 1rem` for example
**[Cheatsheet for Flexbox on CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**
/EDIT

Span doesn't seem very semantic, maybe use an unordered list?

If I understood well your problem, you want as many span per line that'll fit but no span begininng on a line and finishing in another line?
Then the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MRR6P/ will do the trick. Try

```
span {
  line-height: 1.8;
  word-wrap: normal;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Author doesn't specify if it's a requirement, but note that `inline-block` still isn't support by many common, but older, browsers.

Comment: Yes he'll have to add the combo `span { display: inline; zoom: 1; }` for IE6 and IE7 only. The only remaining problem will be with Firefox 2 (solution `display: -moz-inline-stack;` with caveats), but Fx2 has died when IE6 is still present in quite a few multinational corp and China :)

Comment: @FelipeAlsacreations This seems to work perfectly. I'm probably not going to need legacy browser support. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

not 100% sure what you mean but if you want each span to display on a different line, then make them display block

```
span { display: block; }
```

edit

maybe

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

like this? http://jsfiddle.net/xNndp/1/  except with no width on the div of course

Comment: No, he doesn't want each span on a new line, he wants each span to not word wrap and only line break in between spans.

Comment: oh i see, well word-break would not work since it will break unbreakable words. need some kind of no wrap thing like on the table cells

Answer (score 0):

So if you would like all those spans to take one line for themselves (thats what I understand), you should use `<p>`s or `<li>`s and not spans. Then, you could use line-height to control the space between lines.

Hell, you could even use `<br>`s to break your lines.

Another method would be to put your spans `display:block`, making them skip a line when they end.

Answer (score 0):

Try using display:block; within the 's css. 
Then adjust the margin/padding for the required spacing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to make the span act like a div?

If so, you could use the following:

```
display: block;
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/xNndp/

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way, though not perfect, is to use `span { white-space: nowrap }`. Of course, if the `<span>` width extends beyond the `<div>` width you're going to have problems. You'll either need to make the `<div>` scrollable, or use JavaScript to fix this scenario.

The other `display` with `white-space` options in the CSS spec aren't cross-browser enough to work the way you want them to.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution. You just need to add a blank to the end of the content in each span or to add a blank between every two spans. It works very well and the print will be pretty!